# numberOfRowsInSection and prepareForSegue method problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to iOS development and I am having a trouble with counting objects from Array which contains Dictionaries.

My data structure looks like this and it's located in another custom class:

[Library header file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYFEJ.png)
[Library implementation file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsnu6.png)

There will be quite a lot of them (now only 4 just for testing) and I need to count NSStrings with key kEviela.

I need this counting to calculate number of rows required for my tableView:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return ?;
```

Also I have a detailView where I need to show each of this String separately. So how can I do this in prepareForSegue method?

Answer (score 0):

It's just

```
return _library.count;
```

which is the number of dictionaries in the array.

Anyway I recommend to map the dictionary to a custom class.

To get an array of all values for key `kEviela` write

```
NSArray *kEvielaArray = [_library valueForKey: kEviela];
```

This is one of the rare cases where `valueForKey`is intended as a KVC method.

Comment: Right dictionary is located in another custom class, so I am trying to get this like this: NSArray *library = [self.eVielasLibrary.library valueForKey: kEviela]; return [library count]; But it shows that library is nil.

Comment: You didn't mention the *other custom class*. Edit your question and add all relevant information how the classes are related.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,i think you can show number of rows by counting your dictionary objects. I use NSMutableArray converting from dictionary because it's easier for me to manipulate.It's totally personal though.

**Also I have a detailView where I need to show each of this String separately.**

What you can do?

There is function called **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** delegate method.

When you select row this function is called.In this function you grab your detailView controller and keep value to one of it's variable(NSString or Something) according to your data.
you can call segue programmatically from here after assigning value.

As an example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];

    detailVC.userName = [userList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];

}
```

or, If you don't want to use like this, then in **prepareForSegue** method (what you called)
grab your destination view controller and assign value just like previous. That's it.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.dictionary = [youdictionary mutableCopy];


        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _library.count;

}
```

Above is the Way you get the count of array check it out.

Here first you have Array and then you can find out the dictionary value.

```
NSString *kEvielaValue = [_library valueForKey: "kEviela"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `[[_library valueForKey: kEviela]count];`

`[_library valueForKey: kEviela]` will pick up an NSArray that contains all the values of `kEviela` and the count message will give you the number of those elements from the main array of `_library`